# Set default language cookie on ASP.Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, multilingual, globalization

I need to implement multilingual asp.nt mvc application and i set current ui thread with httpmodule below:

```
public class CookieLocalizationModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // eat the cookie (if any) and set the culture
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["lang"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["lang"];
            string lang = cookie.Value;
            var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lang == "en" ? "en-US" : "tr-TR");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        }
    }
}
```

I set language cookie on Global.asax's Session_Start() method because i need to set different language cookie based on request url host (i have multiple sites in mvc application)

When first launch of application in context_BeginRequest() method cookie value is null, so thread culture is not set properly.

Where should i set default cookie (i need to look at url host) ?

Answer (score 0):

First time you can get language from **HTTP Header**. Here is the code snippet
    public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        string cultureName = null;

```
    // Attempt to read the culture cookie from Request
    HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
    if (cultureCookie != null)
        cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
    else
        cultureName = Request.UserLanguages != null && Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0 ? 
                Request.UserLanguages[0] :  // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages
                null;
    // Validate culture name
    cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // This is safe

    // Modify current thread's cultures            
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

    return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
}}
```

I am also managing a multilanguage website and I define language in URL Route (e.g. websitename/en/Home/Index)

You can also refer this article, everything explained about Multilanguage site.

I hope this will help you.

Thanks